# What is the maximum charging current supported by Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, charging

As the title says: What is the maximum charging current supported by Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300)?

Comment: I found that my old s3 would not charge at all with a high current charger and I had to revert to a lower current one. Mind you, the battery was totally dead though that should not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a 2A Samsung charger and USB doctor and Samsung Chargring Current Lite app, I found that the MAX current reported by both USB doctor and Samsung Charging Current Lite App is 1A(1000 mA).

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abmantis.galaxychargingcurrent.free&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

There are various apps on the Play Store where you can check your current charge current and your "maximum" (not sure how accurate the calculation is)

Via USB the maximum is 460mA with an average of 460mA

Via AC the maximum is 1000mA with also an average of 1000mA

Comment: This is accurate information - the S3 has a max charge rate of between ~900mA-1A.

Comment: Wireless charging also has a maximum of 460mA wherever its USB or AC

Would I be right in saying @IAmTheSquidward that the average charging current may be affected by how old a battery is?

Comment: Yes and no.  The battery has integrated circuitry that dictates the incoming current - it will only pull what it needs.  As a battery gets older, it won't hold a charge as well, but it shouldn't need less current.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward - If you can back that claim up, enter it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get my fully depleted battery to charge over 450 at first, but once it had some charge, it was up to 1200 by end of the cycle (average) with a peak of 1800.  I then hit reset and it dropped to 540 (battery at 100%).

I can only assume the battery itself then, dependimg on its level of charge, will draw at a variable rate.

Answer (score 0):

Current is drawn from the load, not pushed from the source (voltage does the pushing).

The wall charger contains only a power supply. The actual charging circuit is in the phone and it's a fairly smart one. It limits the amount of current the battery can draw regardless of the current available whether 1 amp, 2 amps or 200 amps.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking: What is the max supported by the charging circuit.